# how to append data using openpyxl python to excel file from a specified row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have different Python list variables(data1, data2, data3 ect) containing data which I want to put into an already existing excel sheet. Presently My loop goes like this.

```
for row, entry in enumerate(data1,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=1, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data2,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=2, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data3,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=3, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data4,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=4, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data5,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=5, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data6,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=6, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
for row, entry in enumerate(data7,start=1):
  st.cell(row=row, column=7, value=entry)
  work.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Once my Python script runs, It will store the data from the  1st row. **If I am again running the script I want the new data to come below the available data**

How to do so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using:

```
sheet.max_row
```

It will return the last row value, you can start writing the new values from there:

```
max = ws.max_row
for row, entry in enumerate(data1, start=1):
   st.cell(row=row+max, column=1, value=entry)
```

Comment: Thats correct. sheet.max_row gives the last row. So in my loop where should i give this value? Is it in the `start=row_number` ?

Comment: Here it shows " PermissionError Errno 13 permission denied"

Comment: Just tried it, Still it says permission denied! Traceback (most recent call last):
 ` writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
  File "C:\Users\rnair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\
openpyxl-2.4.0a1-py3.5.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 230, in save
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\rnair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\zipfile.py", l
ine 1009, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample.xlsx' `

Comment: Try keeping only one save method call that is after all the writings were completed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had actually kept the excel file opened in the side. When I close it and run the program, it works perfectly

Answer (score 24):

**openpyxl** has many different methods to be precise but **ws.append** in previous answers is strong enough to answer your demands. Consider you have written your data to a new **sample.xlsx**:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

headers       = ['Company','Address','Tel','Web']
workbook_name = 'sample.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
page = wb.active
page.title = 'companies'
page.append(headers) # write the headers to the first line

# Data to write:
companies = [['name1','address1','tel1','web1'], ['name2','address2','tel2','web2']]

for info in companies:
    page.append(info)
wb.save(filename = workbook_name)
```

Now, to append new lines you must first open an existing book with **load_workbook**:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook_name = 'sample.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(workbook_name)
page = wb.active

# New data to write:
new_companies = [['name3','address3','tel3','web3'], ['name4','address4','tel4','web4']]

for info in new_companies:
    page.append(info)

wb.save(filename=workbook_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

`ws.append()` will always add rows below any existing data.

Comment: So, in my example you are saying, instead of work.save, I should use work.append?

Comment: It says "Workbook object has no attribute called append"

Comment: I see that you have answered this same question for someone else where you advised him to specify the path of the excel file while creating it.  As i am not creating any file and just using the available one, do I need to specify too??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the append() method to append values to the existing excel files.
Example:

```
workbook_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFilePath)
sheet_obj = workbook_obj.active
col1 = 'NewValueCol1'
col2 = 'NewValueCol2'
sheet_obj.append([col1, col2])
workbook_obj.save(excelFilePath)
```

here the col1 and col2 values will be added with the existing data in the excel sheet.