# Openpyxl error - Existing charts and graph being modified in excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using Openpyxl package to append rows(numeric data) in an excel sheet through python script. The excel document consists of 3 sheets with graphs and charts in other sheets. So, whenever the python script is being run and I open the excel to see the changes, the charts and graphs in other sheets are deleted and shows error. Please find the screenshot attached.

[image: Error]

Can anyone please let me know how I can avoid this and is there any feature in openpyxl which will not overwrite existing chart data in excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

When you use openpyxl to append rows, if the graph or charts is on the row that will be append by your code. You need to reassign a new cell for them first. **And for openpyxl, for example you have a graph from 'A1' to 'C5', the 'A1' will be the cell to contain the graph, other cells like 'A2','B3' will be none.** I think that might be the cause of the deletion of your graphs. And you need to close the excel file when the script is running, **only open it after the script is done.**

And use the exact sheet you want to make change on:

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
    wb1 = wb['sheetname']
```

I will use statement like the one below to move the location of an existing element.

```
sheetname['A1'].value = sheetname['B1'].value
```

And here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182528/how-to-append-data-using-openpyxl-python-to-excel-file-from-a-specified-row) to a similar question.

Comment: Actually, the charts and graphs are in different sheets. The excel document consists of 3 sheets. Openpyxl is appending rows in 1st sheet but graphs and charts data in other sheets are modified. I have edited my original question. Thank you for the quick response

Comment: Aha, that's weird. Did you modify the data with the sheet object. I updated the answer.

Comment: Initially I am checking if some columns are present in excel and if they are available then new data is appended in that sheet. I am not modifying any data in the sheet which contains graphs and charts...

Comment: Can you post your code in the question section? It's very unusual for openpyxl to make change on a sheet that you didnot not call in the code. You can also try to save the new result to a new xlsx to see what will you get via `openpyxl.Workbook().copy_worksheet()`

Comment: I have attached screenshot of error message from excel for your reference..

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl does not seem to consider all chart properties when reading existing Excel files. I created a corresponding issue ticket and example code here:

https://github.com/theorchard/openpyxl/issues/47

Answer (score 0):

Another possible source of chart issues I faced with openpyxl is the format of color codes. When using a hex color code, e.g. "#112233" instead of "112233". Openpyxl did not warn me about the need to use a different color format. When opening the resulting Excel file, I got an error message similar to yours.