# How to add data to an existing excel file with openpyxl using Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

SOLVED

I have a template that in a worksheet named "MyData" ill write data.

I am doing :

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(template)
ws = wb['MyData']
for finding in data['runs'][0]['results']:
    ruleIndex = finding['ruleIndex']
    comment = data['runs'][0]['tool']['rules'][ruleIndex]['name']
    ????
    row = row + 1
```

How to write my comment with is in the column G with with row which is incremented in my loop?
like ws[G{row}] = comment ?
this doesn't work

and if I delete everything and just try `wb = load_workbook(template)`
I get:

> C:\Users\XX\PycharmProjects\JSONtoExcel\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py:312:
> UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be
> removed   warn(msg)

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without any knowledge of your data.

Comment: But the [openpyxl tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) shows that you should basically modified `ws` or `wb` in place, and then use `wb.save()` when you're done. Can you show the part of your code where you try to save the results?

Comment: actually this is the part I have problem with. I don't know how to same data in a for loop when I know the column but the row will incrementally change

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your `comment = ...` line at all. You're not giving us enough information. What is `data`, what is its structure? Can you turn your code into a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) so we can cut and paste your code, run it on our machine and analyze it? If you need help modifiying `ws`, make your question focus just on that, not on the other data we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
wb = load_workbook(template)
ws = wb['MyData']
for finding in data['runs'][0]['results']:
    ruleIndex = finding['ruleIndex']
    comment = data['runs'][0]['tool']['rules'][ruleIndex]['name']
    ws[G + str(row)] = comment
    row = row + 1
```

Comment: Openpyxl might cause issues when appending to exiting files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68023552/openpyxl-error-existing-charts-and-graph-being-modified-in-excel/