# how to append dataframe in existing sheet of excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xmlwriter

You can find what I've tried so far below:

```py
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('C:/Users/Abhijeet/Downloads/New Project/Masterfil.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/Abhijeet/Downloads/New Project/Masterfiles.xlsx', engine='openpyxl',mode='a',if_sheet_exists='replace') 
df.to_excel(writer,'b2b')

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate Sample data

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe Name and Age columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Col2': [10, 0, 30, 50]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

This code will add two columns, Col1 and Col2, with data to Sheet1 of sample.xlsx.

To Append data to existing excel

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# new dataframe with same columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['E','F','G','H'],
                   'Col2': [100,70,40,60]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
# try to open an existing workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
# copy existing sheets
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
# read existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r'sample.xlsx')
# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.close()
```

This code will append data at the end of an excel.

Check these as well

[how to append data using openpyxl python to excel file from a specified row?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37182528/14045537)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have excel file **abc.xlsx.**
and You Have Dataframe to be appended as  **"df1"**

1.Read File using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("abc.xlsx")
```

2.Concat Two dataframes and write to **'abc.xlsx'**

```
finaldf = pd.concat(df,df1)
# write finaldf to abc.xlsx and you are done
```